# Playwright test generator in component test

Tags: playwright, component-testing

I recently discovered this very cool feature of Playwright, the ability to generate tests from user actions (https://playwright.dev/docs/codegen#introduction), and I was wondering if it is possible to use this inside component tests (https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components). I have not found any info in docs. Do someone know if this can be done ?
Thank you.